# Why is the Tools-Namespace URL also working for the Bind-Namespace?

Tags: android, xml

I just saw that we are using the Tools-Namespace URL also for the Bind-Namespace:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    [...]

            <include
                android:id="@+id/button_view_dealer_search_filters_select_all"
                layout="@layout/layout_list_item"
                bind:isListItemBottomDividerVisible="@{true}"
                bind:isListItemTopDividerVisible="@{false}"
                bind:itemEndMargin="@{@dimen/layout_list_item_padding}"
                bind:itemStartMargin="@{@dimen/layout_list_item_padding}"
                bind:itemTitle="@{@string/dealersearch_filter_category_all}" />

    [...]

</layout>
```

I suspected it would not work but it does. My information was to use the App-Namespace URL for it: `xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: Seeing the namespace prefix bindings alone is insufficient to answer your question.  Realize that the prefix part (e.g. `bind`) is insignificant apart from the namespace URI part, (e.g. `http://schemas.android.com/tools` or `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`), and an unused namespace prefix has no significance at all.

Comment: @kjhughes I know that. That was not my question. I am asking, how it is that my bind calls are working with either Namespace-URL?

Comment: Then why haven't you updated your question to show if and how the namespace prefixes are being used?